# Set notation for graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am new to set theory and graph theory but have been asked to provide a formal model and so I'm on a steep learning curve. Having got my head around a lot of the notation I am struggling with the following problem:

I have defined a set of hosts in a computer network $h \in H$ and a set of connections C between hosts $C \subseteq V \times V$ where I express this as a graph $G = (V, E)$ where V is the set of hosts and each E is are the edges representing the connections between the hosts.

Now what I would like to do is apply a label function to each node which I have stated is $\phi : H \to I$ to represent the inbound connections. Inbound connections are the sum of all of the edges (i,j) where j = the specific host. Any help on how I should express this?

Apologies if any of my notation is not quite correct, as I say I'm still learning. If anyone has any links to resources that might help I would appreciate this. A lot of answers that google throws up for set theory and graph theory are basic examples from what I have found.

Comment: When you say "sum of edges", do you mean the sum of values on these edges? Or do you mean the number of edges that are inbound?

Comment: I mean the number of edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! I don't have a comprehensive knowledge of resources in these domains, so I'll stick to giving an answer to your problem.

First of all, you have some redundant notations: in your graph $(V,E)$, the set of vertices $V$ is exactly the set $H$. For simplicity's sake, I'll replace all occurrences of $H$ with $V$. Moreover, the labels you want to put on your nodes are simply nonnegative integers. You are therefore looking for a function $\phi:V\rightarrow\Bbb N$, where $\Bbb N$ is the set of nonnegative integers.

Now for some set theory. For each node $j\in V$, you are looking for the set of other hosts $i$ such that $(i,j)$ is a connection. In terms of sets, you are looking for the set
$$\{i\in V:(i,j)\in E\}.$$
The label function takes a host $j$ and returns the number of inbound connections, i.e. the cardinality of this set. Therefore
$$\phi:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
V & \rightarrow & \Bbb N \\
j & \mapsto & \#\{i\in V:(i,j)\in E\}
\end{array}\right.$$
where $\#$ is the cardinality of a set.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem exactly. Having got an understanding of basic set theory do you recommend any resources for understanding set theory applied to graphs at all i.e. in this case which involves applying the concept of sets to ordered pairs of graph edges?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any specific resources. All I can say is what you're looking for sounds like graph theory, specifically for directed graphs. But maybe you already know those terms :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, your $H$ and your $V$ are the same thing: the hosts or nodes (A.K.A vertices in the graph).

In that case, if $E$ represents the connections between hosts (A.K.A edges in the graph), then the inbound connections you're referring to would be the equivalent to the *degree* of each of your vertices.

Regarding the degrees of vertices there's a thing called *incidence matrix*, maybe that's what you're looking for.

Hope any of that helps.

Comment: You can use `*italics*` to get *italics* :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks!